# @Test(enabled=false) is not shown as skipped test case

Tags: selenium, testng

We have a number of TestNG tests that are disabled due to functionality not yet being present (enabled = false), but when the test classes are executed the disabled tests do not show up as skipped in the TestNG report. We'd like to know at the time of execution how many tests are disabled (i.e. skipped). At the moment we have to count the occurrences of enabled = false in the test classes which is an overhead.

Is there a different annotation to use or something else we are missing so that our test reports can display the number of disabled tests?

For example below method still gets executed : -

```
@Test(enabled=false)
        public void ignoretestcase()
        {
            System.out.println("Ignore Test case");
        }
```

Comment: Please provide code for reporting. How do You do Your report.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SkipException`

```
throw new SkipException("Skip the test");
```

Check this post [Skip TestNg test in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724418/skip-testng-test-in-runtime)

Comment: but its asking me to delete the below coded lines when i added the above line. 

@Test(enabled=false)
public void blankfields() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InterruptedException
{
 throw new SkipException("Skip the test");
 DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
(Its asking me delete the above line)